# Threading Question - Best way to spawn multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've created a method, let's call it MemoryStressTest(). I would like to call this from another method, let's call it InitiateMemoryStressTest(). I would like the InitiateMemoryStressTest() method to call multiple instances of MemoryStressTest() via different threads. The threads don't need to be aware of each other and will not be dependent on each other. I'm using .NET 4. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You do know about `GC.AddMemoryPressure()`, do you? Using Threads seems overcomplicated here. Especially using more than 1 extra Thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be as simple, as possible:

```
        int threadCount = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        {
            (new Thread(() => MemoryStressTest())).Start();
        }
```

Comment: Actually that inner line isn't simplicity itself. Wouldn't hurt to break it up with an extra var.

Answer (score 4):

If you *just* want new threads - and don't want thread pool threads, tasks etc, then it's very straightforward:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(MemoryStressTest);
    t.Start();
    // Remember t if you need to wait for them all to finish etc
}
```

(One benefit of this approach over using the thread pool is that you don't get the "smart" behaviour of .NET in terms of ramping up threads in the thread pool slowly etc. All very well for normal situations, but this is slightly different :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using .NET 4.0 Parallel Framework's tasks instead of threads
- let the system decide how many actual threads to use.

This can be done with a parallel for, or other techniques.

Comment: Well, the default threading implementation used by the TPL is the ThreadPool, which throttles back thread creation to avoid bogging down the CPU with too many threads. That wouldn't be much of a "stress test".

Comment: Aren't memory stress tests supposed to be bandwidth tests (i.e. MB/s).

Comment: Technically yes, but in that case, using the ThreadPool would reduce bandwidth, by throttling back threads.